# When I should use transformation of inputs variable in neural network?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, precision

I have run ANN in matlab for prediction a variable based on several response variables.ALL variables have numerical values.I could not get a desirable results although I changed hidden neuron several times many runs of the model and so on.My question is should I use transformation of the input variables to get a better results?how can I know that which transformation I should choos?Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly advise you to use some methods from time series analysis like lagged correlation or window lagged correlation (with statistical tests). You can find it in most of statistical packages (e.g. in R). From one small picture it's hard to deduce whether your prediction is lagged or not. Testing huge amount of data can help you in revealing true dependencies and avoid trusting in spurious correlations.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, Can you specifically name the package that you are talking about.I am new to R.